# Impact of learning a new language on productivity

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

Are there any scientific studies (and conclusions) about the impact of mastering a new programming language over previously learned programming languages? I'm particularly interested if mastering various languages can decrease average productivity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm particularly interested if mastering various languages can decrease average productivity.

I strongly doubt this. Since I learned functional programming, I've improved the way I'm writing my Java (non-functional) code as well. Learning new languages poses a great programming exercise that hardly decrease your productivity.

Comment: I clarified the question. I'm sure we can all do stuff in many languages, and being able to learn from each one is highly beneficial. However, I highly doubt most programmers master more than 2 or 3 languages.

Comment: Depends on who you call a programmer, but I'd say the opposite, most programmers *do* know more than 2 or 3 languages.

Comment: I think hgpc is saying that while most programmers probably *know* many languages, very few programmers will truly master more than 1 or 2 languages

Comment: Ah, ok, sounds closer to the truth. Still though, I sincerely doubt that mastering multiple languages is a drawback when it comes to productivity.

Comment: @aioobe, can you tell us which functional language you've picked up?

Comment: @duffymo, Scala, and some OCaml (through the use of [coq](http://coq.inria.fr/)) Specifically, my way of thinking about immutable objects have changed.

Comment: Nice, thank you.  I'm dipping my toes in the Scala pool now, too.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how long did it take you to achieve your current level of mastery?  Is your experience limited to exercises, or have you written a complete application?

Comment: @duffymo, I've done mostly small programs. Like solved (and constructed) some lab assignments in some cs-courses. I'll be doing my first real application (a aspect-like compiler for a subset of Java) in the beginning of next year).